# MVVMLight toolkit Messenger class causing problems. Firing N times

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a view named Work.xaml. This Work.xaml contains multiple WorkSkeleton.xaml. The Work.xaml's ViewModel is WorkViewModel.

The Work.xaml is contained in MainPage.xaml which has button to load Work.xaml. I hope I am clear till now. The button's event handler is simple :-

```
 private void hypMyWork_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ShowGridContent(new Work());
        }

 private void ShowGridContent(UserControl control)
        {
            gridContent.Children.Clear();
            gridContent.Children.Add(control);
        }
```

In my Work.xaml.cs's Constructor I have registered for Messages of type ObservableCollection:

```
    Messenger.Default.Register<ObservableCollection<WorkEducation>>(this, "BindWorkEducationList", collection =>
    {
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            if (item.IsEducationInfo == false)
            {
                WorkEducationSkeleton skeleton = new WorkEducationSkeleton();
                skeleton.WorkEducation = item;
                stkPanel.Children.Insert(0,skeleton);

            }
        }
    });
```

The ViewModel is sending this message when the ObservableCollection is loaded like this :-

```
 Messenger.Default.Send<ObservableCollection<WorkEducation>>(WorkEducation,
                    "BindWorkEducationList");
```

Everything works fine the 1st time. But as soon as I click the Work button in MainPage.xaml to load the Work page 2nd time, the messages are received in my Work.xaml 2 times which adds the same items to stackpanel again and again. This happens N times. If I clicked the button Nth time the message will be received N times in Work.xaml.cs. But how is this possible?

I have clearly specified the recepient in Work.xaml.cs to be `this` as the 1st parameter which means the message is to be received for this particular instance. On click of Work button the instance is completely new. Then why is it firing N times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure it's firing N times for the same instance? You probably have N instances lying around (N-1 waiting to be garbage collected) and that's why you're seeing it N times.

Comment: Sorry it is not problem of Messenger class. On further investigation I found my viewmodel itself is making a call many times which is why the message is firing N times. I need to now inspect my View Model.

Comment: That is most probably the cause indeed. Remember that weak references do not mean that the recipient will unregister automatically. To ensure a clean workflow you should add an "unregister" workflow when the view is deactivated.

Comment: I was having the same problem in my navigation app. Moving to different pages and coming back to the original page message were received multiple times. As Laurent suggested I "Unregister" the messenger and it worked. Thanks